# Deserialize nested properties

Tags: servicestack

I am using ServiceStack.Text to deserialize a response like so:

```
 var obj = JsonObject.Parse(response);
```

The problem is that it only deserializes top level properties.

I tried playing around with some settings like:

```
JsConfig.Init(new ServiceStack.Text.Config
{
    IncludeTypeInfo = true,
    ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true
});
```

but doesn't change anything.

How do I fully deserialize response including nested objects without a concrete type?  (my goal is to be able to access deep values by string)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse arbitrary JSON with ServiceStack, [use JSON.parse()](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils#install) from **ServiceStack.Common** NuGet package:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

ServiceStack.Text JSON Serializers is primarily for deserializing JSON into **Typed** models.